# Taipy long_callback don't actualize the value

Tags: python, callback, taipy

I am using a long callback for a DAQ arduino-based to test a 4x4 matrix keyboard. I need to actualize some status buttons to represent if any key is pressed (for example, I had to reduce to two status buttons and simulate two states, low and high for one arduino analog input. The "lov" for the status button is the variable "keypad[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZbHR.png)" and the variable "keypad_choice_1" associated with the key and status. I add two buttons, the first to start  the acquisition and the second to reset the screen to low values. The problem is that after a "high input", "start", "reset" , "low input" and "start" again, the status does not actualize in the screen to the low value and stays in high.
I'm updating the state variable in the status_DAQ function, but when returning to the hard function for a second call, it seems that there is a residual value of the variable allocated in memory. What might be the problem?

CODE:

```
from taipy import Gui
from taipy.gui import State, invoke_long_callback, notify
import numpy as np
import time
import os 


keypad  =   {1:[('E', '1'), ('S', '1'), ('W', '1')],2:[('E', '2'), ('S', '2'), ('W', '2')]}

keypad_choice_1 =   keypad[1][0]
keypad_choice_2 =   keypad[2][0]

keypad_choice   =   {1:keypad[1][0],2:keypad[2][0]}

status  =   0
value_tgg   =   'High'
test_time   =   5


def on_reset(state):
    state.keypad_choice_1=state.keypad[1][0]
    state.keypad_choice_2=state.keypad[2][0]
    state.keypad_choice={1:state.keypad[1][0],2:state.keypad[2][0]}
    print('after reset click')
    print(state.keypad_choice_1)
    print(state.keypad_choice[1])
    print('******')


def on_action(state):
    notify(state, "info", "Heavy task started...")
    print('after start')
    print(state.keypad_choice_1)
    print(state.keypad_choice[1])
    print('******')
    invoke_long_callback(state,on_DAQ,[state.test_time,state.value_tgg],status_DAQ,[],500)

def status_DAQ(state,status,keypad_choice):

    notify(state, 'i', f"Status parameter: {status}")

    if isinstance(status, bool):
        if status:
            notify(state, 'success', "Finished")
            print('Notify: before finish')
            print(state.keypad_choice_1)
            print(state.keypad_choice[1])            
            state.keypad_choice_1= keypad_choice[1]
            print('Notify: after finish and assign the new value')
            print(state.keypad_choice_1)
            print(state.keypad_choice[1])
            print('******')    
            state.status=0
        else:
            notify(state, 'error', f"An error was raised")
    else:
        state.status += 1


def on_DAQ(test_time,value_tgg):
    i=0
    starttime = time.time()
    
    while i<2:

        #This if simulate a read analog input for a Arduino DAQ
        if value_tgg == 'High':
            print('AI-high')
            C4=0.   
            C3=0.
            C2=0. 
            C1=0.22
            L4=1
            L3=1 
            L2=1 
            L1=0.5
        else:
            print('AI -low')
            C4=0.   
            C3=0.
            C2=0. 
            C1=0.
            L4=1
            L3=1 
            L2=1 
            L1=1

        lin_Teclas = np.array([[C1, C2, C3, C4]])
        col_Teclas=1-np.array([[L1,L2,L3,L4]])
        Teclas=np.matmul(col_Teclas.T,lin_Teclas)
        indexPress=Teclas.nonzero()        
        if indexPress[0].size == 0 :
            aux_valindexPress=0
        else:
            valindexPress=4*indexPress[0]+indexPress[1]+1
            aux_valindexPress=valindexPress[0].item()

        if aux_valindexPress==1 and i==0:
            keypad_choice[1]=keypad[aux_valindexPress][1]
            i+=1
        elif aux_valindexPress==2 and i==1:
            keypad_choice[2]=keypad[aux_valindexPress][1]
            i+=1
       
        aux_valindexPress=0
        telaps=round((time.time()-starttime),2)
        if telaps >test_time:        
            i=3

    return keypad_choice


page1_md= """
## TEST
number refresh notifications <|{status}|>

#####Time for hard function
<|layout|columns = 200px 200px 200px
<|
Time (seg)
<|{test_time}|number|>
|>
|>

<|{value_tgg}|toggle|lov=High;Low|>

<|
<center>
| <|{keypad_choice_1}|status|lov={keypad[1]}|> | <|{keypad_choice_2}|status|lov={keypad[2]}|> | 
</center>
|>


<|START|button|on_action={on_action}|id=btn01|>

<|RESET|button|on_action={on_reset}|id=btn01|>

"""


Gui(page1_md).run(use_reloader=True,port=50000)
```

Comment: What's up with all the `\[`, `\]` in the code? After fixing those it still doesn't run anything - just opens a blank page. What does Arduino have to do with this?

Comment: I had fixed the \ [ , \ ] problems. To post the question I removed the arduino code part and simulated the inputs (C1 to C4 and L1 to L4 are the analog inpus simulated) to someone without arduino run the code with (I simulated using the if "value_tgg == 'High' or else"). The problem really not is about arduino, is about Taipy long callback, then I eliminated the arduino tag. If you run the code after install taipy libraries the program open a webpage where executes the interface for the Python program

Comment: I am not sure to understand the issue. Why do you not have these assignments in `status_DAQ`?

```python
state.keypad_choice = keypad_choice
state.keypad_choice_2= keypad_choice[2]
```

Alongside your assignment:

```python
state.keypad_choice_1= keypad_choice[1]
```

What are you supposed to update, and to which value?